# Dropping dimension of Tensor with size bigger then one tensor, in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

First i splitted the original tensor and then after some operations i want to combine the tensor to the original shape and the original tensor, before splitting it. I'm not sure i can just use the old tensor with graph mode in tensorflow.

Each dimension of the four dimension of tensor_a has at least a size of 2.

```
tensor_a = tf.split(tensor_c, split_into, axis=1)) # creating additional dimension

# some operations

tensor_a = tf.convert_to_tensor(tensor_a)
first, second, third, fourth = tensor_a.shape
tensor_b = tf.reshape(tensor_a, (second, first * third, fourth))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is self-contained, and shows a couple of ways of reconstructing the original tensor after splitting. I think the second approach, using tf.concat() instead of tf_convert_to_tensor() is the neatest. I'm hoping the code is self-explanatory.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Construct a test tensor, to be split and then reconstructed
tensor_c = tf.reshape(tf.constant([i for i in range(24)]), [2,6,2])
print("tensor_c")
print(tensor_c.numpy())

# Split it, as the question does
list_of_tensor_a = tf.split(tensor_c, 3, axis=1)
print("\nlist_of_tensor_a")
print([t.numpy() for t in list_of_tensor_a])

# Create a tensor shape (3, 2, 2, 2), as the question does
# This changes the original ordering of tensor_c. It was split on axis 1, 
# and is now reassembled by creating a new axis 0
tensor_a = tf.convert_to_tensor(list_of_tensor_a)
print("\ntensor_a")
print(tensor_a.shape)
print(tensor_a.numpy())

# Reshape as in the question. 
# Does not reconstruct tensor_c, since the ordering has been changed
first, second, third, fourth = tensor_a.shape
tensor_b = tf.reshape(tensor_a, (second, first * third, fourth))
print("\ntensor_b - incorrect reconstruction of tensor_c")
print(tensor_b.numpy())

# Correct reconstruction, first approach. 
# Use tf.transpose() to restore the original order
tensor_b2 = tf.reshape(tf.transpose(tensor_a,[1,0,2,3]), (second, first * third, fourth))
print("\ntensor_b2 - correct reconstruction of tensor_c")
print(tensor_b2.numpy())

# Correct reconstruction, second (and neater) approach. 
# Use tf.concat() instead of tf.convert_to_tensor()
tensor_b3 = tf.concat(list_of_tensor_a, axis=1)
print("\ntensor_b3 - correct reconstruction of tensor_c")
print(tensor_b3.numpy())
```

Comment: thank you, i updated my question, maybe you can answer the question now more directly?

Comment: tf.split() returns a list of tensors,not a tensor. So I don't understand how tensor_a in what you describe can be a tensor

Comment: i used tf.convert_to_tensor(), i am feeding an RNN with smaller sequences, that's why i used the split method, but i need the original shape at the end.